# Optimizing string searching in xml node

Tags: python, xml, performance, lxml

I have a very long xml document (100k lines), and I'd like to see if a string is contained in it. Here is how I'm currently doing it:

```
'HDRENT' in etree.tostring(node)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I don't think it's necessary to print the entire xml document, if I can do it in a more straightforward/faster manner.

Comment: Is the string a value contained withing element tags, or is just anywhere in the xml?

Comment: @James no it's within the text of the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xpath:

```
node.xpath("count(//text()[contains(.,'HDRENT')]) > 0")
```

this should return true if the 'HRDENT' appears within the text of the html tags, false otherwise.

If 'HRDENT' appears within the tag's attributes, use:

```
node.xpath("count(//*[@*[contains(.,'HDRENT')]]) > 0")
```

Comment: what if the string is not in the text of the element? For example, in my case it is `<Offer Type="HDRENT">...</Offer>`.